# Center align span inside anchor tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
    <div>
        <ul>
            <li class="dropdown">
             <a href="link" class="col-xs-12">
                <span class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                    <span id="image" class="col-xs-3"><img src="/home" width="100" height="100" /></span>
                    <span id="display_name" class="col-xs-6">  @Name </span>
                    <span class="caret"></span>
                </span>
              </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

I need center span element which contains name is always align at middle of anchor tag. I don't want to set height and line height of the a tag. Because the name length may vary. so a tag height also will differs. Whatever the name entered I need to align it to center. How to achieve this ?

Comment: center vertically or horizontally?? and where is the anchor tag in you code??

Comment: Have you tried `margin: auto`?

Comment: Yes. margin: is not working

Comment: have you tried text-align:center ?

Comment: Can u paste your css or using code snapper?

Comment: there is no anchor tag buddy in your code..

Comment: You want vertical center? or hirizontal center?

Comment: I need to align vertically center.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use this `display:table` and `display:table-cell` structure for vertically align it to center.

```css
 a {
   display: table;
 }
 a span {
   display: table-cell;
   vertical-align: middle;
 }
```

```html
<div>
  <ul>
    <li class="dropdown">
      <a href="link" class="col-xs-12">
        <span class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                    <span id="image" class="col-xs-3"><img src="/home" width="100" height="100" /></span>
        <span id="display_name" class="col-xs-6">  @Name<br>@Name<br>@Name </span>
        <span class="caret"></span>
        </span>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

> In above snippet no matter how long is the name it will automatically align it to center

Answer (score 1):

CSS-tricks has a [guide](https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/) on how to center things, vertically or horizontally.

```
.parent {
position: relative;
}
.child {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

This means that, implemented in your code, it will look like this:

```
<div>
    <ul>
        <li class="dropdown">
         <a href="link" class="col-xs-12">
            <span class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                <span id="image" class="col-xs-3"><img src="/home" width="100" height="100" /></span>
                <span id="display_name" class="col-xs-6">  @Name </span>
                <span class="caret"></span>
            </span>
          </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.col-xs-12{
  position: relative;
}
.col-xs-6{
  position: absolute;
  top:50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

This might need a little tweaking, since the positioning is absolute and you have two other elements, but it should work just fine.

Comment: This makes my text to right side and caret symbol to left side. But aligning vertically middle. I have tried float: none. But not working.

Comment: Have you tried the other alternatives? There are multiple on the css-tricks page i linked to in my answer.